# PayPal Checkout Subscription Change Amount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal

How can I change the amount of a PayPal Subscription with react-paypal-js

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import {
    PayPalScriptProvider,
    PayPalButtons,
    usePayPalScriptReducer
} from "@paypal/react-paypal-js";

const ButtonWrapper = ({ type }) => {
    const [{ options }, dispatch] = usePayPalScriptReducer();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch({
            type: "resetOptions",
            value: {
                ...options,
                intent: "subscription",
            },
        });
    }, [type]);

    return (<PayPalButtons
        createSubscription={(data, actions) => {
            return actions.subscription
                .create({
                    plan_id: "P-3RX065706M3469222L5IFM4I",
                })
                .then((orderId) => {
                    // Your code here after create the order
                    return orderId;
                });
        }}
        style={{
            label: "subscribe",
        }}
    />);
}

export default function App() {
    return (
        <PayPalScriptProvider
            options={{
                "client-id": "test",
                components: "buttons",
                intent: "subscription",
                vault: true,
            }}
        >
            <ButtonWrapper type="subscription" />
        </PayPalScriptProvider>
    );
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Is P-3RX065706M3469222L5IFM4I your own plan ID, or not?

You can create your own plans via:

- Sandbox: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/billing/plans
- Live: https://www.paypal.com/billing/plans

The account used must correspond to the client ID you load the JS SDK with.

---

If the amount needs to change arbitrarily rather than selecting from pre-created plans, then next to the plan_id you can specify a `plan` object to override its values.  This is documented in the [Create Subscription API operation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_create).